# EF4 - insert only if a column has a unique value?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Assume a simple blog-like scenario, where posts are stored both by id and a SEO friendly slug.  Is there a way to check that the slug doesn't already exist during insert?  I mean, I could always do something like:

```
var check = context.Posts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.slug == slug);

if (check != null)
{
    // slug already exists - modify or throw exception
}
else
{
    // save as normal
}
```

But that seems woefully inelegant to me.  I assume there's a better way, but am unsure of what it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the appropriate table in the underlying database.

Comment: Okay, but how would I handle a non-unique slug attempting to be inserted in that case?  Would I need to catch an exception?  Do something else?

Comment: Yes, you should catch a `System.Data.UpdateException` while trying to call `context.SaveChanges()`. An `InnerException.Message` now will be a message from SQL Server and looks like 'Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint...'

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid to throw exceptions when is possible and use them only to handle "proper" exceptions which means something you could avoid to happen.

There is nothing wrong with your code anyway